# Getting invalid identifier even though column exists

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table test_tab1(
seq_id NUMBER(10),
e_id NUMBER(10),
jira_key VARCHAR2(20),
stage_code NUMBER(10)
);

INSERT INTO test_tab1 VALUES(1,11,'JIRA_A',2);
INSERT INTO test_tab1 VALUES(2,12,'JIRA_B',3);
COMMIT;

create table test_tab2(
seq_id NUMBER(10),
e_id NUMBER(10),
jira_key VARCHAR2(20),
stage_code NUMBER(10)
);
```

Can anyone tell me why I am getting the `n.stage_code invalid identifier` error in the below code even though this column exists?
Expected should be that this query should not give this error since this column exist in the WITH sub query clause.

```
WITH  got_new_code  AS
      (
        SELECT m.e_id,m.jira_key
        ,      m.stage_code AS new_code
        ,      c.code
        FROM  test_tab1 m
        CROSS APPLY (
                    SELECT LEVEL - 1 AS code
                FROM   dual
                CONNECT BY LEVEL <= m.stage_code + 1
                  )      c
        WHERE m.stage_code IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY m.e_id,m.stage_code
      )
      SELECT   *
      FROM     got_new_code n
      FULL JOIN test_tab2 t USING (e_id,jira_key,stage_code);
```

Database version: Oracle 18c.

Comment: Because of the alias m.stage_code AS new_code. there is no stage_code in got_new_code.

Comment: You gave `m.stage_code` the alias `new_code`, so you can only refer to it by that name. Try your select without the join to see what you CTE looks like

Comment: @Praveen I tried giving ```new_code``` but still the same error I am getting. Also I am giving giving all the column in the result of SELECT clause of cte but getting the same error

Comment: @HoneyBadger Yes I had tried this earlier but got stuck. I need to JOIN ```test_tab2``` table but getting this error. Without JOIN I am getting the result but with JOIN its throwing an error

Comment: @Vicky commented alias pls see this link [https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=56c8e840b2c9e7e84060b341f406d9c8]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `USING` clause which specifies `stage_code` as a column to join the left and right tables on and there is no `stage_code` from the `got_new_code` sub-query factoring clause as it has been aliased to `new_code`.

Either don't use `USING` and specify the join conditions manually or ensure that both sides of the join have all the columns in the `USING` clause:

```sql
WITH  got_new_code (e_id, jira_key, new_code, code) AS (
  SELECT m.e_id,m.jira_key
  ,      m.stage_code
  ,      c.code
  FROM  test_tab1 m
        CROSS APPLY (
          SELECT LEVEL - 1 AS code
          FROM   dual
          CONNECT BY LEVEL <= m.stage_code + 1
        ) c
   WHERE m.stage_code IS NOT NULL
   ORDER BY m.e_id,m.stage_code
)
SELECT *
FROM   got_new_code n
       FULL JOIN test_tab2 t
       ON (   t.e_id       = n.e_id
          AND t.jira_key   = n.jira_key
          AND t.stage_code = n.new_code );
```

or

```sql
WITH  got_new_code (e_id, jira_key, stage_code, code) AS (
  SELECT m.e_id,m.jira_key
  ,      m.stage_code
  ,      c.code
  FROM  test_tab1 m
        CROSS APPLY (
          SELECT LEVEL - 1 AS code
          FROM   dual
          CONNECT BY LEVEL <= m.stage_code + 1
        ) c
   WHERE m.stage_code IS NOT NULL
   ORDER BY m.e_id,m.stage_code
)
SELECT *
FROM   got_new_code n
       FULL JOIN test_tab2 t USING (e_id,jira_key,stage_code);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=041facbbc60d54bca5f299b99fc38cc2)*

Answer (score 2):

You can either remove the `new_code` alias:

```
WITH  got_new_code  AS
      (
        SELECT m.e_id,m.jira_key
        ,      m.stage_code
        ,      c.code
        FROM  test_tab1 m
        CROSS APPLY (
                    SELECT LEVEL - 1 AS code
                FROM   dual
                CONNECT BY LEVEL <= m.stage_code + 1
                  )      c
        WHERE m.stage_code IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY m.e_id,m.stage_code
      )
      SELECT   *
      FROM     got_new_code n
      FULL JOIN test_tab2 t USING (e_id,jira_key,stage_code);
```

or change the join from `using` to `on`:

```
WITH  got_new_code  AS
      (
        SELECT m.e_id,m.jira_key
        ,      m.stage_code AS new_code
        ,      c.code
        FROM  test_tab1 m
        CROSS APPLY (
                    SELECT LEVEL - 1 AS code
                FROM   dual
                CONNECT BY LEVEL <= m.stage_code + 1
                  )      c
        WHERE m.stage_code IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY m.e_id,m.stage_code
      )
      SELECT   *
      FROM     got_new_code n
      FULL JOIN test_tab2 t
      ON t.e_id = n.e_id AND t.jira_key = n.jira_key AND t.stage_code = n.new_code;
```

... which gives the joining columns twice; so you probably want to coalesce those back to a single occurrence.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=05418e425ea7c0b62d70e45bc837ac7a)